# See intellisense suggestions in mvc views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using MVC5 on visual studio 2017.
I have made an empty controller and have written my code, after that now i have passed a model object to my view.
now i am trying to code my view side but i have these issues:
(i have read the similar question and couldn't fix these)

1- Although i have written below  code as first line in my view but i cannot use intellisense suggestion for my model class.(i found it from one of the similar questions)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Myclass>
```

2- I am using c# common keywords such as "foreach" but when  i write  let's say "fore" in the view it does not suggest me anything. while in the controller it suggests all of them.

Comment: Please post the view you have written and where you are expecting to see the intellisense suggestions.

Comment: its a very empty model with only the above line in top of it. now i am trying to start coding my view bu i cannot see any suggestion from intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

In Razor Views whenever you want to use C# common keywords you must prefix it with the @ sign

So using what you have after declaring your model, you can loop through the collection and for example create a table

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Myclass>

@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   <tr>
     <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field1)
     </td>
      <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field2)
     </td>


   </tr>
 }
```

Comment: i know it and i use it, i mean that the intellisense is not able to suggest the foreach after @ sign.